# Getting data into a node script - more complex than command line arguments

Tags: node.js, command-line-arguments, stdout

I split my tasks into multiple node scripts, "node programs" that will be run individually with `node program1.js`, `node program2.js`, etc. using Node's child process `exec` function in other Node apps.

This way things split up and I can reuse one program in multiple other apps.

It's easy to get data **out of** a node program like that, you just throw whatever data you want to stdout and have `exec` capture it on the other end.

For putting data **into** a node program, how? This is easy if the data is only simple command line arguments, but how would I put arbitrary data (binary, JSON, whatever) into it (at or close the point where I would call `exec`)? Maybe some piping? Example code I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `env` property to pass environment variables to a spawned child process. You can do this in `exec()`, but for spawning Node processes it's better to use `fork()`, since it creates a new instance of V8, which is what you're doing.

This is how you'd pass an environment variable:

```
var exec = require('exec');
var child = exec(command, {
  env: {
    buffer: new Buffer(8),
    json: JSON.stringify(json),
    string: 'a simple string'
  }
}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  // execution callback
});
```

And this is how you'd use the variables in your child process:

```
process.env.buffer
process.env.json
process.env.string
```

Comment: What does exec do if not start a completely new process? Also, into env, can I put anything I want including whole objects of my choice (not just buffers, jsons or strings)?

Comment: The functions `exec()` and `fork()` do both start a completely new process. It's just that `fork()` was specifically created to start new Node processes. And yes, you can store any type of variable into `env`.

Comment: Ok, but fyi it seemed that a boolean inside the env object didn't work. I ended up putting a stringified json (as you did) inside env that wraps everything I need, works fine.